# In Google Cloud Translation API output, the translated output text is overlapping on top of the input text, making the output unreadable

Tags: google-translation-api, google-cloud-translate

I am using Google Cloud Translation API to convert English PDF document to Hindi PDF. Normal case I will receive the output as a single output PDF document with translated PDF text. But in some cases (I have seen this when pdf size is low) the translated output will be a pdf where output text is overlapped over the input text. The translated output is correct, but it is not readable since it’s printed on top of input text. How can I fix this issue?

I need the translation output in a clean pdf with translated output text only or in an editable .docx file with just translated text.